# c# - Xamarin forms Error in nuget packages when import PCl project in vs 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

i get this errors when i import **PCL** project in **vs 2017**
i want Guaranteed way to run this project
and install this packages successfully
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Syncfusion NuGet feed as a package source.

For Syncfusion´s Xamarin packages: https://nuget.syncfusion.com/nuget_xamarin/nuget/getsyncfusionpackages/xamarin

Here you can find all Syncfusion's feeds: https://nuget.syncfusion.com/